# Yup Regex Instagram hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex, formik, yup

I've been trying to find/create a regex to validate Instagrams hashtag & mentions (User handles) using Yup within Formik.

I've found a [post](https://blog.jstassen.com/2016/03/code-regex-for-instagram-username-and-hashtags/) which is almost what I need, however, my regex is rusty & I can't seem to get it working correctly.

```
// Regex for hashtags
/^(?:#)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)/gm

// Within schema
hashtags: Yup.string()
  .required('Tags are required')
  .matches(
    /^(?:#)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)/gm
  )
```

What is currently passing

```
#foo #bar
#foo,#bar
#foo#bar
#foo bar
#foo,bar
```

Desired pass

```
#foo #bar
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/wYK2CN/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is working perfectly within regex101, however, it's not working as expected within Yup.match. #foo #bar still fails, however, #foo bar passes. It's looking like this is something more specific with Yup than just regex alone.

Comment: Instagram now have hashtags with emoji. This regexp won't detect them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have for instagram hashtags within Yup. Works perfectly for us. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wYK2CN/2).

```
/^(?:#)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:(?!))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)((?: #)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?))*$/
```